# How do I decode FTP file read from BytesIO

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to read the contents of text files on an FTP server, my code can make a connection and list all files present in the directory. However, it is failing here:

```
from io import BytesIO
import os

r = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + "textfile.txt", r)    
print (r)
```

This prints:

```
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x03C2CCF0>
```

Firstly I'm not entirely sure what this means so If someone could shed some light on that I would be grateful.

Also when I try the following code to decode the returned value I get this error:

```
TypeError: '_io.BytesIO' object is not callable
```

Code looks like this:

```
r = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + "textfile.txt", r)    
print (r.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `r.write` and `r.getvalue()`

```
from io import BytesIO
from ftplib import FTP
import os

ftp = FTP('ftp.test.org') 
ftp.login()

r = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + "textfile.txt", r.write)    
print (r.getvalue())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Comment: BytesIO has no attribute `value`

Comment: then take a look in the documentation. The function is "getvalue".

Comment: cheers, this still returns coded values and I don't know what they mean

Comment: @EcSync So show us what exactly do you get. We cannot help otherwise.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it returns `<built-in method getvalue of _io.BytesIO object at 0x035CCD50>` as I say, I do not know what this means, whether it is specific information or a generic result from the function i used.

Comment: you have forgotten the round brackets  in getValue()  ?

Comment: Hi just wondering how to write unit test / mock this piece of code, especially the `BytesIO` bit?